# The sensitivity of the finger swipe on the screen

Tags: java, android, android-sensors, android-gesture

I'm using `GestureDetector.OnGestureListener` to invoke method when user moves finger across the screen in the specified direction.
**My problem** - just move slightly and the method is called, I would like the user to move his finger a little more on the screen.

```
public class SwipeListener extends GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener {
     public static final int MIN_SWIPE_DISTANCE = 40; 


    @Override
    public boolean onDown(MotionEvent e) {
        return true;
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX, float velocityY) {
       float xDiff = e1.getX() - e2.getX();
       float yDiff = e1.getY() - e2.getY();
       return resolveSwipe(xDiff, yDiff);
    }


    private boolean resolveSwipe(float xDist, float yDist) {
        float yDistAbs = Math.abs(yDist);
        float xDistAbs = Math.abs(xDist);

        SwipeDirection swipeDirection;


        if (yDistAbs > xDistAbs) {
            if (yDistAbs < MIN_SWIPE_DISTANCE) {return false;}
            swipeDirection = (yDist > 0) ? SwipeDirection.DOWN: SwipeDirection.UP;

        } else {
            if (xDistAbs < MIN_SWIPE_DISTANCE) {return false;}
            swipeDirection = (xDist > 0) ? SwipeDirection.RIGHT: SwipeDirection.LEFT;
        }

        onSwipeEvent(swipeDirection);
        return true;
    }

    private void onSwipeEvent(SwipeDirection swipeDirection) {
        if (swipeDirection == SwipeDirection.UP) {

            return;
        }
        if (swipeDirection == SwipeDirection.DOWN) {

            return;
        }
        if (swipeDirection == SwipeDirection.LEFT) {
         finger1()
            return;
        }
        if (swipeDirection == SwipeDirection.RIGHT) {
            finger1();
            return;
        }

}

public enum SwipeDirection {
    UP, DOWN, LEFT, RIGHT
}
```

Is it possible? What should I change or add here?

Comment: If this value changes then nothing changes

Answer (score 0):

You need to calculate as to what level of x-axis or y-axis you don't want to perform any action on swipe.

Answer (score 0):

You have to declare minimum distance for swipe as `private static final int SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE = 160` may be it will help you [Click here to implement it](http://www.ssaurel.com/blog/implement-a-gesture-detector-in-android/)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/16892191)

Comment: @jwenting Thanks for suggesting